# VBA: How to edit Attribute inside a Procedure?

Tags: vba, attributes

I recently discovered that is possible to use `Attribute [ProcedureName].VB_*`, inside procedures.

### What I found

But this code is not shown inside VBA Editor.
[image: Same code in VBA Editor (left) and exported *.cls in Notepad (right)]
*Same code in VBA Editor (left) and exported .cls in Notepad (right)*

When `Attribute` is written inside VBA Editor, it's marked red
[image: Attributes added manually in the VBA Editor]
*Attributes added manually in the VBA Editor*

### The question

Is there more elegant way how to maintain these Attributes than export class module, edit them outside and import them back (facepalm needed)?

Also I haven't found official documentation for these Attributes (on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/).

Thank you!

PS: As always I hitted something interesting and related just after Question had been sent. A step-by-step [example on Microsoft Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-for-eachnext-statements#using-a-for-eachnext-loop-to-iterate-over-a-vba-class) suggests to do it by Export-Edit-Import method :(

Comment: [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) seems to be cool think! Thanks! But I can't figure how to use it for managing these Attributes. This is what I see in `VBE`, `Code Explorer` and `Notepad++` ([screenshot](https://ctrlv.link/shots/2020/12/10/PqRu.png)) after I tried to add `Annotate` `@Description`.

Comment: You can see the description in the comment is different from actual `Attribute` value in Notepad.

Comment: Acc. to Rubberduck [Wiki Page](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations#user-content-module-annotations:~:text=When%20synchronizing%20attributes%2C%20this%20will%20add%20or%20update%20the%20module's%20VB_Description%20hidden%20attribute%3A), actual `Attributes` are changed during `Attribute Sync`. Can't find where to force this sync.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks for reply. But still no luck [Screenshot](https://ctrlv.link/shots/2020/12/10/Spym.png). I hit a button in red rectangle for sync. No errors thrown. Then exported file and no actual `Attribute` set here.

Comment: Solved: It doesn't add `Attribute` on Refresh, but missing attribute warning is shown  in `Code Inspection` window. Where its possible to solve it (force to add the `Attribute`) via right click on the problem menu ([screenshot](https://ctrlv.link/shots/2020/12/10/tcDC.png)). Thank you @freeflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for getting Rubberduck to apply annotations requires a few steps.

1. Execute a Rubberduck refresh.  If the code does not compile cleanly then Rubberduck will show a 'Parse Error'.  In this case you need to sort out your code first.  This can be an issues if you are applying Rubberduck to an existing code base.  If not then learn to compile and rubberduck.Refresh early and regularly (i.e. after every complete edit)
2. If Rubberduck parses successfully you then need to look at Rubberduck.Code Inspections.  To take action about an inspection result select the individual result and right click.  This will provide a list of actions that can be applied by Rubberduck.

Comment: This comment just provide link to Rubberduck addin homepage: [https://rubberduckvba.com](https://rubberduckvba.com)